# Need to skip certain cells when tabbing through a MS Word Table

Tags: microsoft-word

I have WORD 2010 on my machine. I am trying to tidy up a table we use alot. It's a very basic document, but has a lot of fields that need to be filled out, though for every field, there is a label field describing it.

eg. (I want WORD not to stop at "NAME", "AGE" or "LOCATION" when tab is hit below)

- Name:  John
- Age: 30
- Location: Dublin

When I search for a solution, I'm getting results that seem to describe indentation etc. I'm not entirely sure if that directly relates to what I need, but I don't really want to rebuild the table.

Is there a way that I can tell WORD to ignore paricular cells in this Table, and just tab on to the next. (The form is protected, and these labels i have described are currently marked as uneditable)

Comment: I think you are looking for form fields in your table.

Comment: Can you elaborate?? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that involves macros, and that article suggests that there's no simple GUI way to do what you're asking.

> http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/SetTabOrder.htm

The article describes assigning bookmark names to fields and then creating an OnExit macro, so that when you Tab out of the field, instead of going to the next field that Word thinks it should go to, you can tell Word to put the cursor in a field of your choosing.

To get to the macro editor, with your document open hit CTRL+F11.

Alternatively, on that same article, there's a link to another article on how to use UserForms to achieve what you're wanting.  A UserForm will pop up a dialogue box, and you can put your fields in there for people to fill in.  Controlling the tab index order in a UserForm is better handled.

> http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/Userforms/CreateAUserForm.htm